# Displaying Data from Php Session

Tags: html, web, shopping-cart, php

im building a website that has a basic online shop, and im storing some data into a php session:

prod_ids - an array that holds product ids
prod_count - an array holding number of product wanted
prod_price - an array holding product prices

I Insert data in the Session with this code i created:

```
<?php 
    $found = false;
    if (isset($_GET["product_id"]))
    { 
        //$_SESSION['prod_ids'] contains product IDs 
        //$_SESSION['prod_counts'] contains item quantities ($_SESSION['counts'][$i] corresponds to $_SESSION['gids'][$i])
        if (!isset($_SESSION["prod_ids"])) 
        { 
            $_SESSION["prod_ids"] = array(); 
            $_SESSION["prod_counts"] = array();
            $_SESSION["prod_prices"] = array(); 
        } 
        //check for current product in visitor's shopping cart content 
        $i=0; 
        while (($i<count($_SESSION["prod_ids"]))&& ($found != true)){  
            if (strcmp($_SESSION["prod_ids"][$i],$_GET["product_id"]) == 0) //increase current product's item quantity 
            { 
                $_SESSION["prod_counts"][$i]= $_SESSION["prod_counts"][$i]+ $_GET["product_amount"]; 
                $found = true;
            } 
            $i++;
        }
        if ($found != true){

                $_SESSION["prod_ids"][$i] = $_GET["product_id"]; 
                $_SESSION["prod_counts"][$i] = $_GET["product_amount"]; 
                $_SESSION["prod_prices"][$i] = $_GET["product_price"]; 
        }
    } 
    header('Location: ../products.html');
?>
```

This run successfully, and products.html is loaded back again.
in the Cart section found in this html file, i am trying to display the data found in the session. I have written this code ina file called "displaycart.php" but it is not working:

```
<?php 
    for ($i=0; $i<=count($_SESSION['prod_ids']); $i++)
  {
    <tr>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_ids"][$i]</td>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_counts"][$i]</td>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_prices"][$i]</td>
    </tr>
  }
?>
```

Any Ideas? This is how im calling the file in the products.html:

```
<div id="shoppingcart" class="cart">
<h2>Cart</h2>
<!--? include="" php="" displaycart=""--> <!--?--></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the Help!

Update: Changed all html files to .php: now error pops up:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in D:\Hosting\10835947\html\worldwideconnect\php\displaycart.php on line 4

Comment: Do you call `session_start()` anywhere?

Comment: yes yes ofcourse....its called at the start of the html file

Comment: Is `<!--? include="" php="" displaycart=""--> <!--?-->` supposed to include `displaycart.php`?

Comment: Do you call `session_start()` in Both files?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to process php in an html file. Is the `displaycart.php` file processing the $_SESSION data correctly?

Comment: ok my mistake... updated to include like this <!--?php include 'php/displaycart.php'; ?-->..... thats correct now right?

Comment: and yes all have the start session command

Comment: @JamesBirkett the displaycart.php code is in the question.... the 2nd set of code

Comment: @user2415416 - You need something like '<?php include 'php/displaycart.php' ?>` to include the file.

Comment: no idea why... but each time i arrange it and save the file on server.... it reverts back to the  <!--?php include 'php/displaycart.php'; ?--> :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `products.html` to **products.php**. This instructs the server to run the php code.

Otherwise you need to tell the server to run .html files as php.

Edit:

have a look at [How to Run PHP Scripts in *.html or *.htm Files](https://www.rssinclude.com/blog/36_how_to_run_php_scripts_in_html_or_htm_files)

Edit:

You need to edit `display.php` so that the html code is returned. You can do this using echo eg.

```
<?php 
    for ($i=0; $i<=count($_SESSION['prod_ids']); $i++)
  {
    echo "<tr>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_ids"][$i]</td>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_counts"][$i]</td>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_prices"][$i]</td>
    </tr>";
  }
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
    for ($i=0; $i<=count($_SESSION['prod_ids']); $i++)
  {
?>
    <tr>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_ids"][$i]</td>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_counts"][$i]</td>
        <td>$_SESSION["prod_prices"][$i]</td>
    </tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: so just renaming the file, and redirections to it?

Comment: Yes. By default most web server setups will not process the php code in html files.

Comment: ok so renaming the files to .php got me somewhere as now an error shows in the displaycart.php:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in D:\Hosting\10835947\html\worldwideconnect\php\displaycart.php on line 4

Comment: hmm why unexpected? cant i write <td>? or should i use echo?

Comment: Sorry for the delay went home from work and had not noticed the error in the php file.

Comment: @user2415416 If this has answered your question pleas accept it :-)